# ServiceStack Authentication IsAuthenticated always false for users authenticated via facebook

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, servicestack

Hi am trying to use OAuth authentication FacebookAuthProvider provided by servicestack

```
 var AppSettings = appHost.AppSettings;
            appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings),
                    new FacebookAuthProvider(AppSettings),
                    new GoogleAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                }));
```

I have implement custom AuthEvents and I have access to authorized user data

[image]

but after RedirectUrl happens in endpoint session is empty and IsAuthenticated property is false
[image]

In the same time from Controller I can see that created session successfully saved in Cache
[image]

This scenario occurred only if user doesn't login in facebook in the browser yet, but for user that already logged in facebook, authentication works fine

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance!

Updates:

Scenario for repsoducing:

1. ensure that you didn't loged in facebook in browser (open facebook.com and log out if need)
2. run web app (project which created with template [mvcauth](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcauth/tree/master/MyApp))
3. try to login via facebook
   3.1. for first attempt you will be redirected to https://www.facebook.com/login.php? page for specify your facebook account credentials
4. after first attempt you will be returned to web app page /Account/Login#s=1 but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false in AccountController.Login and you still unauthorized.
5. after second attempt you will finally successfully logged in

At the same time after first attempt Session with user data will be created and saved in Cache, it looks like after redirecting from page 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'  а new session being created without auth data, but for second attempt we successfully login, maybe the core of issue is redirection from 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'

Comment: This sounds like the Auth wasn’t successful, is the redirect url suffixed with a #f or a #s?

Comment: The redirect url looks like `Account/Login#s=1`

Comment: What is your current `Startup.cs`? Have you placed `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc`

Comment: Yes, in Startup.cs I have app.UseAuthentication(); before app.UseMvc
Login with username/password works as expected
If I logged in facebook on another tab of my browser and then again try authenticate from my web app via facebook I will successfully logged in. 
Also after first authentication attempt (that complete, as I described, with IsAuthenticated = false) when I press login via facebook button in my web app again I successfully loggin in (without need input my facebook credentials again).

Comment: What project template did you start with?

Comment: I'm using Aps .Net Core 2.2 MVC, with follow ServiceStack nuget packages: ServiceStack 5.6,  ServiceStack.Mvc 5.6, ServiceStack.Server 5.6, ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Core 5.6

Comment: Did you start with [mvc](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvc) or [mvcauth](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcauth) or something else? If not, try starting with one of those projects and copy over your Facebook Auth to test if it works in a new project.

Comment: Follow your advice I ran project with [mvcauth](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcauth) template, and got exactly the same result, after first attempt of login via facebook in method MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.Login property IsAuthenticated = false , but from second attempt login login completed successfully and IsAuthenticated = true
I used out of box configuration

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use ServiceStack.Auth in MVC and vice-versa you'll need to register the `NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider` which provides integration between ServiceStack Authenticated Sessions and ASP.NET Core's Claims Principal, e.g:

```
public void Configure(IAppHost appHost)
{
    var AppSettings = appHost.AppSettings;
    appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings), /* Use ServiceStack Auth in MVC */
            new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings),     /* Sign In with Username / Password  */
            new FacebookAuthProvider(AppSettings),        
            new GoogleAuthProvider(AppSettings),          
            new MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider(AppSettings),  
        }));

    appHost.Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature()); //Enable /register Service

    //override the default registration validation with your own custom implementation
    appHost.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for updates, but looks like it doesn't solve an issue, please take a look I've updated the question with scenario for reproducing